# Question on Wilson's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

So I am given to calculate $\gcd(n! +1, (n+1)!)$.

I found out that if $n+1$ is prime then $\gcd(n! +1, (n+1)!) =n+1$ and $1$ otherwise. So, I started by assuming that there exists a prime such that $p |n!+1$ and $p|(n+1)!$ which is equivalent to saying $n! +1 \equiv 0\implies n! \equiv -1 \pmod p$ and $(n+1)! \equiv 0 \pmod p \implies n!(n+1) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and since  $n! \equiv -1 \pmod p \implies n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p.$   Thus $p|n+1$ but $n! \equiv-1 \pmod p$. So can we say by Wilson's Theorem $p = n+1$?

Comment: I wouldn't say "by Wilson's theorem" (because you're asserting its converse really); I'd just say that if $p<n+1$ then $p\mid n!$, which is impossible.—By the way, note that the computation you did is essentially noting that the gcd must divide any linear combination of $n!+1$ and $(n+1)!$, and in particular must divide $(n+1)(n!+1)-(n+1)! = n+1$.

Comment: ahhh i got it!!!!! So basically if $p < n+1$ then $p \leq n$ which means $p < n!$ hence $p|n!$ but by our computation above we have established that $p|(n! +1)$ then this means $p | 1$ but this isnt possible since $p$ is a prime. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome! I would omit the "$p<n!$" from your chain of reasoning, because $p<n!$ doesn't imply $p\mid n!$—we do need the stronger $p\le n$.

Comment: got it thanks!!